# how attribute class js on a svg

Tags: javascript, svg

hi i am trying to attribute a class current or active on some part on my svg: actually only on the smallblue circle:

```html
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <circle id="greycircle" fill="none" stroke="#727272" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249" cy="248" r="200"/>
            <circle id="smallgreytop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249" cy="47.667" r="5"/>
            <circle id="smallgreyleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="449" cy="247.667" r="5"/>
            <circle id="smallgreybottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249" cy="447.667" r="5"/>
            <circle id="smallgreyright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="49" cy="247.667" r="5"/>
            <circle id="bluecircle" fill="none" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249" cy="248" r="200"/>
   <a xlink:href="#firstPage"><circle id="smallbluetop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249" cy="47.667" r="5"/></a>
            <a xlink:href="#secondPage"><circle id="smallblueleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="449" cy="247.667" r="5"/></a>
            <a xlink:href="#3rdPage"><circle id="smallbluebottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249" cy="447.667" r="5"/></a>
            <a xlink:href="#4thpage"><circle id="smallblueright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="49" cy="247.667" r="5"/></a>
 
            </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("smallblueleft").setAttribute("class", "whateverClassYouWantToApply");
```

This will work on your current code because you have no other classes set on that element.  If you did have other classes set, this statement would remove the others.  To avoid that effect, you can add the new class to the existing set like this, in most browsers (but not Internet Explorer earlier than version 10):

```
document.getElementById("smallblueleft").classList.add("whateverClassYouWantToApply");
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("smallblueleft").className` won't work on svg elements because it's unfortunately not a `DOMString` but a read-only `SVGAnimatedString` object. I'd recommend just using `setAttribute` for the class attribute, unless `classList` is available.

Comment: @ErikDahlström, good point, thanks - have edited answer to reflect.